# Wireless is detected, but not connecting. Ethernet works. How to correct the wireless address?

Tags: wireless, networking, internet

I am running Ubuntu 14.04 with cable internet, and my wireless is detected and connected, but I cannot connect to the internet. I know the problem is with my machine because other machines are connecting to the same router just fine. I can connect via ethernet just fine as well.

Here are some notable tests:

`ping 192.168.0.105` works with 0% packet loss, but `ping 192.168.0.1` has 100% packet loss.

When I plug in my ethernet, `ping 192.168.0.1` works with 0% packet loss.

My wireless name is `tg`, and the router ip is `192.168.0.1` (where I can enter username and password). I suspect that I need to change my wireless address from `192.168.0.105` to `192.168.0.1`. Any suggestions on how to proceed?

extra info:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ iwconfig
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:"tg"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 00:02:6F:83:F8:F4   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=62/70  Signal level=-48 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:52  Invalid misc:166   Missed beacon:0


[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ ifconfig
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f0:de:f1:b2:53:53  
          inet addr:192.168.0.100  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::f2de:f1ff:feb2:5353/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:980003 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:498384 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1320506168 (1.3 GB)  TX bytes:59780591 (59.7 MB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f3a00000-f3a20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:21927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:21927 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:1781719 (1.7 MB)  TX bytes:1781719 (1.7 MB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 24:77:03:29:8f:dc  
          inet addr:192.168.0.105  Bcast:192.168.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::2677:3ff:fe29:8fdc/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:11828 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:15444 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:4855662 (4.8 MB)  TX bytes:2250585 (2.2 MB)


[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ lspci -nn | grep 0280
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Ultimate-N 6300 [8086:4238]
 (rev 3e)                                                                               



[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

with ethernet unplugged:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ route -n | grep UG
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 wlan0
```

with ethernet plugged in:

```
[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ route -n | grep UG
0.0.0.0         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0




[lucas@lucas-ThinkPad-W520]/home/lucas$ nm-tool

NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [tg] ----------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             connected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        24:77:03:29:8F:DC

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           52 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    tatum:           Infra, 40:8B:07:D8:A5:04, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 

42 W
    PA WPA2
        ums:             Infra, 00:20:A6:72:52:BF, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59
        Alpha 40:        Infra, 28:CF:E9:86:59:5D, Freq 5260 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 30 W
PA WPA2
    thepromiselan:   Infra, 58:6D:8F:51:E5:54, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 $
PA WPA2
    xfinitywifi:     Infra, 06:1D:D5:84:27:A0, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 52
    *tg:             Infra, 00:02:6F:83:F8:F4, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 73 W
PA2
    ums:             Infra, 00:20:A6:A1:9F:25, Freq 2452 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 44
    BRIAN-PC_Network:Infra, 20:AA:4B:DD:93:D6, Freq 2462 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 35 W
PA2
    HOME-C0F8:       Infra, 44:32:C8:D2:C0:F8, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 40 W
PA WPA2                                                                                 
    abcsexy:         Infra, 28:28:5D:27:5D:85, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 27 W
PA WPA2                                                                                 

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.105
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1


- Device: eth0  [Wired connection 1] -------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        F0:DE:F1:B2:53:53

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes
    Speed:           100 Mb/s

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         on

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.0.100
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.0.1

    DNS:             192.168.0.1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put up Ethernet Interface

```
sudo ifconfig eth0 up
```

acquire ip. Use any of the below( Whatever works)

```
sudo dhclient eth0
sudo dhclient3 eth0
sudo dhcpcd eth0
```

Comment: My wireless is now working, thank you! Can you elaborate just a bit on how this works? From my understanding, `sudo ifconfig eth0 up` brings up the ethernet interface, allowing it to to send and receive information (if it wasn't already up). Then `sudo dhclient eth0`  renews the dynamically-assigned IP address of the primary ethernet device. But why do we renew the ethernet IP address, and not the wireless (ie using `sudo dhclient wlan0` instead)? How does bringing up the ethernet interface and renewing the ethernet's IP address fix the wireless IP address?